# Understanding MATLAB Graticules in Meshgrat and Pcolorm

Tags: matlab, gis

I'm having trouble understanding what *precisely* the output of `meshgrat` means and how this relates to the `lat` and `lon` parameters of `pcolorm(lat,lon,Z)`. I have a grid of global data, I'll call `Z`, at a 1.5 degree latitude x 1.5 degree longitude spatial resolution. Thus I have a matrix that's 120 x 240 (180 degrees of latitude / 1.5 = 120, 360 degrees of longitude / 1.5 = 240). Row 1 is 90 N and column 1 is 180 W (-180).

If I follow the MATLAB [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/meshgrat.html), I can use `meshgrat` to produce the `lat` and `lon` arguments that I need to supply to `pcolorm` as follows.

```
latlim = [-90 90]; 
lonlim = [-180 180];
[lat,lon] = meshgrat(latlim,lonlim,[120 240]);
```

However, I don't understand why the spacing of the output is the way it is. For example, the first five values of `lat` are [-90.0000, -88.4874, -86.9748,-85.4622,-83.9496...]. The `lon` values follow the same spacing. The spacing is very close to 1.5 degrees, but it isn't. Why is there a discrepancy? The documentation claims that the paired `lat` and `lon` values are the location of the graticule *vertices*. In that case, these values make some sense, since there will always be one more vertex than actual grid cells. To test this, I made the following adjustment to the `meshgrat` code by adding one extra row and column:

```
latlim2 = [-90 90]; 
lonlim2 = [-180 180];
[lat2,lon2] = meshgrat(latlim2,lonlim2,[121 241]);
```

This did, indeed, produce the expected output, with the spacing now exactly at 1.5 degrees (i.e [-90.0000, -88.5000, -87.0000, -85.5000, -84.0000...]). Again, this is logical if these are viewed as vertices. But under this scenario `lat` and `lon` no longer match `Z` in size, which goes against how the documentation says to treat `lat` and `lon` in this case.

There seems to be a mismatch here: either the spacing in the `lat` `lon` grids are not accurate, or the girds are not the same size as the data, which would be fine in my mind as long as MATLAB knows how to interpret them accordingly, but the documentation does not seem to suggest using it this way. I have no detailed knowledge of how the MATLAB functions work at a finer level. Can someone explain to me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Thus I have a matrix that's 120 x 240 (180 degrees of latitude / 1.5 = 120, 360 degrees of longitude / 1.5 = 240).

180/1.5 is indeed 120. But you also have an element at 0deg (presumably). That's 121.

Comment: Yes that's true, 0 is included, but if you divide the range -90 to 90 into segments of 1.5, you get 120, since one of the endpoints won't translate to an actual segment. A segment is equivalent to a cell here. So unless I'm completely wrong here, I don't think this resolves it. I drew a number line to check my sanity. If you draw a number line from -9 to 9 (including 0), and then put markers at each end and every 1.5, you get 12 segments of length 1.5. Multiplied by 10 that's 120. A latitude grid of 1.5 degree resolution should have exactly 120 grid cells.

Comment: A number line from -9 to 9, divided by 1.5 has 12 segments. It has 13 indices.

Comment: Yes...but the segments are the cells. This is what my post is about. The mismatch between whether we are using the cells or indices (or vertices). The gridded data will be in cells. There is one data value per cell, not vertex. So the grid is 120 x 140. `meshgrat` seems to deal in vertices, not cells. So it wants 121 x 241 to produce the appropriate `lat` `lon` spacing. But, and this is the confusing part, the documentation indicates that in this case the `lat` `lon` graticules should be the same size as the data grid, which seems to be asking the vertices to equal the cells, which can't be.

Comment: Ah, but the signature pcolor(X,Y,C) operates on vertices, not cells. Edit: even pcolor(C) operates on vertices.

Comment: You might consider this post, https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/585665-pcolorm-ignores-lines-of-data

Comment: Thanks, this helps, although if the following is true as someone in the link you shared stated: "I have to adjust the input to pcolor to take into account the function's behaviour by repeating the last row and column of the data and modify the [x,y] coordinates by shifting a "half dx and a half dy" and add a last column and row to both." Then this seems pretty ill-suited for geographical data. The documentation of `pcolorm` says nothing of having to do such convoluted work arounds, but the behavior I'm seeing seems to support that solution.

Comment: I can agree with that! Best of luck.